# How do I model a polymorphic has_many relationship in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, has-many, polymorphic-associations

Imagine I have a model called `Course` and each course has_many `Modules`. However I want the modules to be a different range of types.

For instance, the `Module` model would be the parent class and would have two fields: `title` and `description` that will be common amongst all types of children.

Now I need `Course` to be able to have any number of `Slideshow`, `Video`, `Image`, `Text` instances, however they must be retrieved through `Course#modules`.

Consider that each child class type has its own attributes, like `Video` could have an `url` field, whereas `Text` could have `contents`, for instance.

What's the right way to model this association?

Comment: This question seems to be similar, perhaps you will find some helpful information here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3209322/rails-polymorphic-has-many

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are 2 options (possibly combined):

- Use polymorphic associations (see ["Polymorphic Associations"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/700148/polymorphic-association) for an example). Your migration should look like:

  ```
  create_table :courses do |t|
    t.references :modules, :polymorphic => {:default => 'Text'}
  end
  ```
- Use Single-Table Inheritance: There your models are subclassed from a common base class, and this is realized on the database by only one table that contains all columns for all model classes.

Have a look at ["Alex Westholms Blog"](http://www.alexwestholm.com/tech/rails-single-table-inheritance-and-polymorphic-associations-some-simple-examples/) about the 2, and the comparison. I think you should go with polymorphic associations, because your modules have a lot of different attributes.

Answer (score 1):

It might be a bit late, but having a model in your application called 'Module' will cause all sorts of problems with name collisions...

Comment: Thanks Jules, but that's a translation from Portuguese "Modulos" which doesn't have name clash issues. But good point!